# Looping addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I console.log(e[i]) in the for loop it gives me a nice print out of all my back buttons, but for some reason when I click on one the event never fires. Thank you in advanced.

```
   function backButtonSubscribe() {
       var e = $('.back');
       var len = e.length;

       for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
           e[i].addEventListener('click',backButtonEvent,false);
       }
    }
```

Comment: where is `backButtonEvent` defined?

Answer (score 1):

As it appears you are using jQuery, why not use this?

```
function backButtonSubscribe() {
    $('.back').click(function() {
        backButtonEvent();
    });
}
```

Why is this in a button press though? What you are doing seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code in the context of the page, I'll just have to guess wildly:

### Guesses

1. You've never called `backButtonSubscribe` in your code, so the function never runs
2. You haven't waited for `document.ready`, or `window.onload`, so no `.back` elements exist when the code is executed
3. You've made a typo in your HTML that we can't see
4. You're using IE, which doesn't support `addEventListener`

---

Looks like you're using jQuery, so you should just bind the event listener as:

```
$('.back').click(backButtonEvent);
```